# Automatically attach sources during import

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with multiple modules and one module uses other modules functions. So, the module with dependencies has the jar file in compile dependencies. So when I try to go to the source, it goes to the .class file from the jar. Instead I want it to go to .java file of the dependent module.

One way is to manually do AttachSources.

Since, I have multiple modules with multiple dependencies;

- Is there a way to get it executed during import by some means, say having a sourcePath.txt with source location under each module.?

Project Structure:

ProjectA :

- ModuleAA  (depends upon ModulesAB)
- ModuleAB  (depends upon ModulesAC)
- ModuleAC

and many more modules.

Answer (score 3):

In order to access the modules' sources from your project, instead to import a jar, you will have to use `compile project (':module')`.

For example, if I have to build your structure, it will look like this:

**ProjectA:** (under com.example.projecta)

```
dependencies {
    ... //Other dependencies(appcompat, jar files...)
    compile project (':moduleaa') //Dependent of moduleAA
    ...
}
```

**ModuleAA:** (under com.example.moduleaa)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project (':moduleab') //Dependent of moduleAB
    ...
}
```

**ModuleAB** (under com.example.moduleab)

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile project (':moduleac') //Dependent of moduleAC
    ...
}
```

**ModuleAC** (under com.example.moduleac)

```
dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Now the ProjectA can access to any modules and their dependencies.

To navigate between your project and the source code of your modules, you can use the short key to show the source. You can find the keymap under: `File > Settings > Keymap > Main menu > View > Jump to source ( or Show source)`. (usually control + left click, or F12).

**EDIT**

If you have a module in an other project that you what to import and be able to modify as if it is a module on your current project, you can modify your settings.gradle of this current project with:

```
include ':module'
project(':module').projectDir = new File("/<path_to_module>/other_project/module")
```

Then the module will appear in your current project.

Comment: As already mentioned, this is not a viable option for me. I need to understand how to make studio take the file sourcePath.txt which contains the source path for the respective module.

Comment: Can you put a pseudo code of what is in your sourcePath ?

Comment: sourcePath.txt contains single line  entry pointing to the src folder of the jar i.e 
"E:\a\b\c\src\"

Comment: @thepace I don' know if you found the solution, but here is another method in my edit.